# Rebasing an existing Pull Request to show only your commits

Tags: git, github, version-control, pull-request

I am working on a feature branch, and it's based off the master branch. I require changes from someone else's feature branch, hence I directly take his branch into mine instead of waiting for it to come via the master branch as a PR merge. Now, when I commit my branch, and create the PR, I can see his commits too, as a part of my PR. How do I make sure that only my commits are shown in this case? Is Rebase the answer? If yes then how can I achieve this?

Comment: Has your problem solved yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `git rebase --interactive master` and then you can pick your commits only and have the rest of them ignored or squashed.

Comment: This will ensure that his changes persist in my branch right?

Comment: @RutwickGangurde yeah, just make sure you squash them into a single commit and they will be there as well

Comment: How will I squash all his changes in a single commit? I read an article which states that 's' will squash the commit into the previous one. When I ran a rebase and squashed one of his into my previous one, it's running through all the commits, and I have to resolve conflicts along the way. How would I do it?

Comment: Here's how I did it. Created a new branch off the master, which had all his code. Cherry picked mine from my PR, and put them in the new branch. Looks okay.